# session destroy after search results shown

Tags: php, session

I had my web application and it has (registration form, adding info, viewing info, and search and all these choices in the same page in navbar menu  )
I start session for each user(when log in) and every thing is OK till I search for something and I got the search result and I go  to the add or view info I found that is logged out that is mean the session destroyed why this is happened ? I want user to be logged in even after I finish search pleas help me and apologize if I have mistaken. 
this is my code for the search part :

```
<form class="navbar-form navbar-left" action=""  method="post">
                <div class="input-group">
                    <input size=55 type="text"   name="search" class="form-control" placeholder="Search">
                    <span class="input-group-btn">
                        <button type="submit"  class="btn btn-default"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></span></button>
                    </span>
                </div>
            </form>


    </nav>
</div>

        <?php
if(!isset($_SESSION)){session_start();}
 $conn = mysql_connect("localhost", "root", '');

  mysql_select_db("db103",$conn);
$user=$_SESSION["myname"];
        $fname = '';

if (isset($_POST['search']))
{
    $fname = $_POST['search'];
}
else{}
if(isset($_SESSION["myname"])){
 $sql = "SELECT * FROM telephone_guide where owner='$user' and (firstName like '%$fname%' or secondName like '%$fname%' or phonenumber like '%$fname%' or celnumber like '%$fname%')";


 $result = mysql_query($sql, $conn) ;

//  number of rows fetched
$num = mysql_num_rows($result);

echo("<div class='styl'>");
echo("<table width=300 border=3 >");

echo("<th>ID<th>First Name<th>Second Name<th>tele-Phone Number<th>cel_phone number<th>Date<th>Address");


 while ($arr = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {


echo("<tr><td><a href='update1.php?id1=$arr[0]'>$arr[0]</td><td>$arr[2]</td><td>$arr[3]</td><td>$arr[4]</td><td>$arr[5]</td><td>$arr[6]</td><td>$arr[7]</td></tr>");


 }
echo("</table>");

?>
<br>
<br>
<?php
echo("</div>");} 

    ?>
```

Comment: **    Note:

    To use cookie-based sessions, session_start() must be called before outputting anything to the browser.
**

Comment: As @tim said, use session_start(); in top of the codes, one time, such a way that run in every pages in your website.

Answer (score -1):

You will need to initialize session before anything
You can also see **ob_start()** and **ob_flush_end()** at the very end of your script. This is to suppress errors arising from packets already sent due to intercalation html within php

So try This

```
<?php
ob_start();
session_start();
?>




<form class="navbar-form navbar-left" action=""  method="post">
                <div class="input-group">
                    <input size=55 type="text"   name="search" class="form-control" placeholder="Search">
                    <span class="input-group-btn">
                        <button type="submit"  class="btn btn-default"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></span></button>
                    </span>
                </div>
            </form>


    </nav>
</div>

        <?php

if(isset($_SESSION)){}



 $conn = mysql_connect("localhost", "root", '');

  mysql_select_db("db103",$conn);
$user=$_SESSION["myname"];
        $fname = '';

if (isset($_POST['search']))
{
    $fname = $_POST['search'];
}
else{}
if(isset($_SESSION["myname"])){
 $sql = "SELECT * FROM telephone_guide where owner='$user' and (firstName like '%$fname%' or secondName like '%$fname%' or phonenumber like '%$fname%' or celnumber like '%$fname%')";


 $result = mysql_query($sql, $conn) ;

//  number of rows fetched
$num = mysql_num_rows($result);

echo("<div class='styl'>");
echo("<table width=300 border=3 >");

echo("<th>ID<th>First Name<th>Second Name<th>tele-Phone Number<th>cel_phone number<th>Date<th>Address");


 while ($arr = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {


echo("<tr><td><a href='update1.php?id1=$arr[0]'>$arr[0]</td><td>$arr[2]</td><td>$arr[3]</td><td>$arr[4]</td><td>$arr[5]</td><td>$arr[6]</td><td>$arr[7]</td></tr>");


 }
echo("</table>");

?>
<br>
<br>
<?php
echo("</div>");} 

    ?>
<?php ob_end_flush(); ?>
```

Comment: " This is to suppress errors" sure why fix errors, when we can just pretend they never happened.

Comment: @NancyMooree sorry but it does not work with me it still log out after I got results search :(